# Locating and playing video files in Processing

Tags: java, video, processing, playback

I'm pretty new to programming using Processing, and cannot find a way to have Processing open and play a video file. I have looked at a few previous questions regarding getting Processing to play videos using Java, but every time I try the code, I get a RuntimeException: Could not load movie file x. I have tried storing the video in different locations on my computer and with different resolutions and encoding, with the same result each time. Here is the code I believe is the closest to working:

```
import processing.video.*;

Movie myMovie;

void setup() {
   fullScreen();
  myMovie = new Movie(this, "hollywood_test.mp4");
  myMovie.play();
}

void draw() {

  image(myMovie,0,0);
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}
```

If anybody knows how I can get Processing to look in the right place to find the video, or if I've made a mistake with the code, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're using a relative path, double check "hollywood_test.mp4" is either in the sketch folder or in the sketch's data folder.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks so much! This was the resolution to the issue

Answer (score 0):

The easy way here might be to just open a fileSelector

```
void fileSelected(File selection) {
  if (selection == null) {
    println("Window was closed or the user hit cancel.");
  } else {
    //not sure about the loadimage for a mp4
    myMovie= loadImage (selection.getAbsolutePath());

    println("User selected " + selection.getAbsolutePath());
  }
}

void load_image(){
  selectInput("Select a file to process:", "fileSelected");
}

void setup{
  fullscreen();
  load_image();
  myMovie.play();
}
void draw(){
  load_image();
  image(myMovie,0,0);
}
```